# What creates thousands of ".dat.nosync" hidden files on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I'm managing many hard drives often shared over the network (SMB).
Every now-and-then I find folders that somehow have thousands or tens of thousands of hidden files like this:

> .dat.nosync40b7.5jNfXw

They are all called .dat.nosync but the "40b7.5jNfXw" seems to be incremental or random.
These files make it impossible to list the contents of a directory sometimes.
And when I just `rm -v '.dat.nosync*'` I get `too many arguments` as there are way too many files.

What is making these weird files and why so many of them?

Comment: might be dropbox or icloud related

Comment: Only ref I can find to them is on https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/issues/2286 `.nosync` files themselves are an indicator to iCloud to not backup, but only one is needed per directory structure. I'm pretty sure nothing Apple is creating them, it has to be third party.

Comment: For now I made a script that scans the drives and finds and deletes these files but this is just fixing the symptom, not the illness. I've been googling and whatnot, but nothing yet. I don't have dropbox and my computers are permanently offline so no iCloud either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out: it's Adobe InDesign. When an external HDD is is shared over SMB, and another computer has an InDesign file open on this HDD, any temporary network interruption causes some infinite loop to create tens-of-thousands of these tiny hidden files.

This was confirmed on Mac OS (various versions) with Adobe InDesign CC 2018.

I was able to remove all these troublesome files and "fix" more then 10 "broken" external drives by running this python script right after mounting the drives:

```
import os

extdrv = '/Volumes/HDD24'

for root, dir, file in os.walk(extdrv):
    for f in file:
        if str(f).startswith('.dat.nosync'):
            print(root + '/' + f)
            os.remove(root + '/' + f)
```

Seems like nobody else has this problem, or they just don't realize that their HDD is not "dying" but full of these tiny files, making it impossible to index or list.

Comment: I am also having those .dat.nosync00fd-files on an SMB share, but I never used Adobe InDesign and those files are on an internal HD, not on an external. Im am sure, these files were written by Xcode, because one of them contains source code and the other one an Xcode project. I am not sure, whether this is a MacOS-X issue or a samba issue or perhaps a MacOS+Samba don't work together well-issue.